# SQL: searching words within string

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, search

I have two string columns:

```
ColA = [apple] [bob] [dog]
ColB = abcdefgh, apple, bob, elephant, dog, etc
```

I am looking for code  that returns true if all items (within the [])  of colA are in ColB. I cannot use the full search Index. Is there any other way to achieve this? Any help would be great.

A row looks like:

```
ID        ColA                                ColB
123      [apple] [bob] [dog]           abcdefgh, apple, bob, elephant, dog, etc
```

Comment: I don't understand.  What does a single row look like?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you for replying Gordon. I have made the changes to question.  I am joining two tables based on condition that  all items in colA in Table1 are present in the ColB of Table 2.

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing multiple codes in a single column is not the SQL way of storing lists.  You want two separate tables, one for each list (in ColA and ColB).  Then your query should be easier to write.

Comment: Do you think I should use python or some other tool to achieve this? I cannot split the lists, as at the end I need them as it is.

Comment: if i want to split the list in colA. How can I do it? I find few methods, but it only gives me first item say "apple", how to get all items? Thank you for helping.

Comment: In case any one had same problem: I created separate column for each item and then executed the query it worked.